# How to Update a Ckeditor enabled field with Jquery

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

I'm having trouble figuring out how to update a field in Drupal which has ckeditor enabled using Jquery. It seems the field no longer responds with the identifier id when ckeditor is activated for that field.

I would like to update a field which has ckeditor enabled when a user completes an action. How can I do this? I have searched and searched and came up with nothing. It seems ckeditor in Drupal is doing something different from the standard ckeditor software.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the code you use to this with ckeditor when it's not inside Drupal? I don't think there's any difference, but seeing the code you know works on a text area in a non-Drupal site should make it easy to spot where the problem with your Drupal-based code is

Comment: Hi Clive, the Jquery code I am using is quite basic. It's just $('#edit-field-operation-hours-0-value').val(newValue); This code will update the field without any issue as long as ckeditor is not enabled on the field. However, if ckeditor is enabled, it seems to create a <body> tag and the text is added inside that tag. I don't really understand it. You can see it in action if you go here: http://yoninja.com/node/add/world-listing. Sorry, you will need to create a user account to access this page to see it unfortunately. But you can see the field under the Location Info & details section.

Comment: And that method works ok outside of Drupal with CKEditor? i.e. `$('#id-of-replaced-textarea').val('foo');` is all you need? CKEditor works using an iframe, so that's why you're seeing another document embedded. That isn't specific to Drupal though, it's just how CKEditor works

Comment: hi Clive...no, this code does NOT work with ckeditor. That's my problem. It works with the standard Drupal field and all the other fields I have on this page. The issue is the CKEDItor enabled field. I don't know what Jquery code (selector) I need to use to do this.